# Magento 2 - View page problem

Tags: magento2, order-status

Issue in order page Issue in order page  Issue in order page Issue in order page 
[image]

[image]

Comment: In Orders page not showing order status but i got orders using API , in this orders have order status, but it not display in Magento

Comment: In Orders page not showing order status but i got orders using API , in this orders have order status, but it not display in Magento

Comment: which magento version you use

Comment: I'm using Magento ver. 2.3.0